# Inkscape wrapping text boxes not visible in HTML

Tags: html, svg, inkscape

I'm using Inkscape to design SVG graphics I want to include in an HTML page. Text boxes that use line wrapping seem not to render when included in an HTML page. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: A fix for what? If it's just that SVG's aren't rendering then first make sure your webhost is supporting the SVG mime type. Other than that, your question is really vague.

Comment: The SVG renders, but the wrapped text box does not. Everything but the text box renders.

Comment: Give an example of the problem, and the desired result. You've been on SO long enough to know the basics man.

Comment: May we see a screenshot of the issue in the question? What font are you using? Would it be an acceptable fix to convert the text to line paths so you don't need to worry about font rendering?

Comment: @halfer That solved the problem, thank you! Feel free to give that answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the problems associated with rendering SVG files is that your target browsers may not have access to the fonts you have on your machine. Additionally, you may find that Inkscape renders to one format of the SVG standard - or even a non-standard extension - whereas browsers may use a different standard.

Fonts are a particular problem in this regard. Thus one solution, if you do not need dynamic text, is to convert fonts to line paths. Bear in mind that it is worth checking your font licensing here - it is possible that you may need a publishing license even if you have converted the string to paths.